# How to change the Hyperlink's colour when the IsEnabled property of a TextBlock is changed?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-style

I am new to WPF. I am trying to change the hyperlink's foreground colour to other colour (say gray) when the `IsEnabled` property of a `TextBlock` becomes `false`. Shall I add a `Style` to achieve my requirement?

I have stuck in here:

```
            <TextBlock Margin="0,150,0,0"
                       TextAlignment="Center" 
                       Background="White" 
                       IsEnabled="{Binding ShowProgressRing}">

                <Hyperlink x:Name="HyperLink"
                           Foreground="Blue"
                           TextDecorations="UnderLine"
                           FontSize="12"
                           FontWeight="SemiBold" 
                           Command="{Binding Path=Command}" >
                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=HyperLinkText}"/>
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Bind the Foreground property to IsEnabled property and use a converter to change colour..

Comment: @VishalPrajapati Thank you. I think this will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when Hyperlink becomes disabled, it changes color to gray by default (if default Foreground isn't overridden), so you can disabled TextBlock and it is done

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,150,0,0"
           TextAlignment="Center" 
           Background="White"
           IsEnabled="{Binding ShowProgressRing}">

    <Hyperlink x:Name="HyperLink"                   
               TextDecorations="UnderLine"
               FontSize="12"
               FontWeight="SemiBold" 
               Command="{Binding Path=Command}" >
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=HyperLinkText}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

if Hyperlink should have non-default active/disabled colors, you can write a style for Hyperlink with a Trigger:

```
<Hyperlink x:Name="HyperLink" 
            TextDecorations="UnderLine"
            FontSize="12"
            FontWeight="SemiBold" 
            Command="{Binding Path=Command}" >

    <Run Text="{Binding Path=HyperLinkText}"/>

    <Hyperlink.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!--binding to the same view model property which sets IsEnabled-->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowProgressRing}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Hyperlink.Style>

</Hyperlink>
```